# Summing data frames with non-numeric values

Tags: r, dataframe

I would like to `sum` dataframes that contain non-numeric arguments. When I do the simple add function I receive the following error: "**Error in FUN(left, right) : non-numeric argument to binary operator"**.

How can I solve this?

ex1:

```
`04:00` `04:10` `04:20`
  <chr>   <chr>   <chr>  
1 a       0       a      
2 0       a       a      
3 0       0       a
```

ex2:

```
`04:00` `04:10` `04:20`
  <chr>   <chr>     <dbl>
1 0       b             0
2 b       0             0
3 b       b             0
```

Desired outcome:

```
`04:00` `04:10` `04:20`
      <chr>   <chr>     <dbl>
    1 a       b             a
    2 b       a             a
    3 b       b             a
```

**Sample code:**

```
sum = ex1 + ex2
```

**Sample data:**

```
ex1<-structure(list(`04:00` = c("a", "0", "0"), `04:10` = c("0", "a", 
"0"), `04:20` = c("a", "a", "a")), spec = structure(list(cols = list(
    `04:00` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), `04:10` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), `04:20` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
"collector")), delim = ","), class = "col_spec"),  row.names = c(NA, 
-3L), class = c("spec_tbl_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
    

ex2<-structure(list(`04:00` = c("0", "b", "b"), `04:10` = c("b", "0", 
"b"), `04:20` = c(0, 0, 0)), spec = structure(list(cols = list(
    `04:00` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), `04:10` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), `04:20` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
"collector")), delim = ","), class = "col_spec"),  row.names = c(NA, 
-3L), class = c("spec_tbl_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: I am having some troubles replicating your ```dput()```. Is that correctly pasted?

Comment: just remove the `problems = <...>,` part of the dputs

Comment: What is the expected result?

Comment: What is a+b supposed to return?

Comment: @OttoKässi there are no instances when a or b infer each other. So if in ex1 at case 1 at 4.00 is a than in ex2 at case1 at 4.00 is 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the test case this works:

```
data.frame(
  Map(\(x, y) ifelse(x == "0", y, x), 
      ex1, ex2), 
  check.names = FALSE)
#  04:00 04:10 04:20
#1     a     b     a
#2     b     a     a
#3     b     b     a
```

This doesn't check if column names match. It simply iterates over the columns of both data.frames simultaneously.

Answer (score 1):

You could first set your zeros to NAs, and then use `dplyr::coalesce` :

```r
l <- map(list(ex1,ex2), ~ mutate(.x, across(.fns = ~ replace(., 0, NA_character_))))
do.call(coalesce, l)

# A tibble: 3 x 3
  `04:00` `04:10` `04:20`
1 a       b       a      
2 b       a       a      
3 b       b       a
```

Comment: `coalesce` assumes that columns from both datasets are the same.

Comment: Mael when i run your code it return ex1

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: It literature returns ex1